# Как сделать такой box-shadow?(фотка)

Tags: css

[image]

Как я могу сделать такой box-shadow, чтобы тонко начинался и утолщался?

Comment: кроссбраузерно - фоновыми картинками

Answer (score 7):

Вот пример:

```css
.box h3{
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
 top:80px;
}
.box {
 width:70%;
 height:200px;
 background:#FFF;
 margin:40px auto;
}
/*==================================================
 * Effect 2
 * ===============================================*/
.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box effect2">
<h3>Effect 2</h3>
</div>
```

То же самое можно посмотреть на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fk5kv/)

Comment: Как я и писал изначально, сделано с помощью свойств :before и :after

Answer (score 3):

Разные варианты теней:

```css
/*Container*/
.container{
 width:900px;
 margin:30px auto;
 padding:25px;
 min-height:400px;
 height:auto; 
}
.container h2 { margin-top:30px;}

.box h3{
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
 top:80px;
}
.box {
 width:70%;
 height:200px;
 background:#FFF;
 margin:40px auto;
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 1
 * ===============================================*/
.effect1{
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
         box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 2
 * ===============================================*/
.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 3
 * ===============================================*/
.effect3
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect3:before
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 4
 * ===============================================*/
.effect4
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect4:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
}  

/*==================================================
 * Effect 5
 * ===============================================*/
.effect5
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect5:before, .effect5:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}
.effect5:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 6
 * ===============================================*/
.effect6
{
   position:relative;       
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
       -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
            box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.effect6:before, .effect6:after
{
 content:"";
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top:50%;
    bottom:0;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
    border-radius:100px / 10px;
} 
.effect6:after
{
 right:10px; 
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
       -moz-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
        -ms-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
         -o-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
            transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 7
 * ===============================================*/
.effect7
{
   position:relative;       
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
       -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
            box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.effect7:before, .effect7:after
{
 content:"";
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
    border-radius:100px / 10px;
} 
.effect7:after
{
 right:10px; 
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
       -moz-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
        -ms-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
         -o-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
            transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 8
 * ===============================================*/
.effect8
{
   position:relative;       
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
       -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
            box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.effect8:before, .effect8:after
{
 content:"";
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
    border-radius:100px / 10px;
} 
.effect8:after
{
 right:10px; 
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
       -moz-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
        -ms-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
         -o-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
            transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
<div class="box effect1">
 <h3>Effect 1</h3>
</div>
<div class="box effect2">
 <h3>Effect 2</h3>
</div>
<div class="box effect3">
 <h3>Effect 3</h3>
</div>
<div class="box effect4">
 <h3>Effect 4</h3>
</div>
<div class="box effect5">
 <h3>Effect 5</h3>
</div>
<div class="box effect6">
 <h3>Effect 6</h3>
</div>
<div class="box effect7">
 <h3>Effect 7</h3>
</div>
<div class="box effect8">
 <h3>Effect 8</h3>
</div>

 
</section>
```

То же самое можно посмотреть на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hancock_888/a5j83/)